# Yammer Autocomplete in SharePoint returns {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} when sending a GET request for groups

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, yammer

For provisioning a Yammer group feed on SharePoint I'm using the autocomplete feature to check if a group exists. Well, this worked fine until "yam.js" API is upgraded to "platform_js_sdk.js". After authenticating I send the next autocomplete request to get a group:

```
yam.platform.request({
    url: 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked?prefix=groupx&models=group:5',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
    success: function (results) {
        callback(results);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        callback([]);
    }
});
```

The response always come into the error handler with the next body: 
readyState":0,
responseText:"",
status:0,
statusText:"error"

I tried ajax too, but without any positive result.

Answer (score 1):

To access the autocomplete api, make sure that you have set your javascript origins in your Yammer App's Basic Info page. For most other endpoints, you can use wildcard subdomains, so for example **https://sharepoint.com** would match all subdomains of sharepoint.com (all office365 SPO sites). However as of 5/17/2014, the autocomplete api appears to have a few issues:

- You cannot use a wildcard subdomain in your origin (have to use the full domain, e.g. https://yourtenantname-my.sharepoint.com)
- The api does not respond to https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked, and you have to use https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked (all the other endpoints use the api.yammer.com domain from the JS SDK).

Comment: Thanks @Adam Toth for your response. In my case I used indeed the wildcard domain https://sharepoint.com to match all SharePoint app domains where the Yammer feed is used. As you can see, I'm talking against the right API endpoint as Yammer has suggested https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked. Anyway, since last week Monday it seems that the autocomplete API does respond to the requests - as I described in the post above. I think Yammer was aware of the issue, so they fixed it.